# Characters being injected into input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I am sure this is something really stupid I am missing.

I am writing a small snippet that adds a hyphen to a string grabbed from an input field. The hyphen is only added once we hit position 4, so I can type 123 and the hyphen will not appear. If I type 1234, it'll automatically change to 1234-. The problem is with handling pasting, somewhere down the line inside jQuery (after my code has executed), it's injecting more characters into the field.

My approach is simple enough. I look at the keyup and keydown event, check the input and insert the hyphen. For pasting I look at the paste even, grab the string, split it and insert a hyphen depending on if one is present or not.

```
$('[id$="field"]').on('paste', function (event) {
    var element = this;
    var text = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text').split('');

    if (text.length > 4 && text.indexOf('-') < 0) {
        text.splice(4, 0, '-');
        $(element).val(text.join(''));
    }
});

$('[id$="field"]').bind('keyup keydown', function (event) {
    var input = $(this).val();

    if (input.length === 4 && event.keyCode !== 8) {
        $($(this).val(input + '-'));
    }
});
```

The `keyup` and `keydown` listener works just fine. If I paste in 12345, I end up with 1234-5 when I hit `$(element).val(text.join(''));` yet afterwards that extra char pops whilst jQuery is doing its thing.

I am rather baffled.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you pasting?  Right click and paste, or Ctrl+V?  Because Ctrl+V is going to fire two keydown and keyup events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are overriding the typical "paste" behavior by updating the value of the input box directly, you need to prevent the "default" paste behavior.

```
$('[id$="field"]').on('paste', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
```